# Queue.put inside a worker thread failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pandas, queue

Inside a worker thread I am generating a data frame . Trying to put this into the queue passed to the worker thread is failing. In fact trying to put any values into the queue is failing.

The part of the code that is failing inside  the worker thread task1() is given below:

```
  df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6]])
    qmdlvalues.put(df)
    mdltiming = time.time() - start
    qmdlparams.put(paramval)
    qtiming.put(mdltiming)
```

Complete code

```
import threading
import queue
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import os
import time

def write_tsne_op(opdata,fname,header):
    with open(fname, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(header)

        for data_slice in opdata:           
            np.savetxt(outfile, data_slice,delimiter=",")

def task1(qmdlvalues,qmdlparams,qtiming,paramval):
    start = time.time()
    #tmpmdl1 = TSNE(perplexity=100,early_exaggeration=1, n_components=2,random_state=0,verbose=1)
    #qmdlvalues.put(tmpmdl1.fit_transform(dense_mx))
    df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6]])
    qmdlvalues.put(df)
    mdltiming = time.time() - start
    qmdlparams.put(paramval)
    qtiming.put(mdltiming)
    print(df)
    print(str(mdltiming))
    print(paramval)

def task2(qmdlvalues,qmdlparams,qtiming,paramval):
    start = time.time()
    #tmpmdl2 = TSNE(perplexity=100,early_exaggeration=10, n_components=2,random_state=0,verbose=1)    
    #qmdlvalues.put(tmpmdl2.fit_transform(dense_mx2))
    qmdlvalues.put(pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6]]))
    qmdlparams.put(paramval)
    mdltiming = time.time() - start
    qtiming.put(mdltiming)

if __name__ == "__main__": 


    dense_mx2 = dense_mx
    dense_mx3 = dense_mx

    qmdlvl = queue.Queue()
    qmdlch = queue.Queue()
    qtme   = queue.Queue()
    mdlvalues = pd.DataFrame()

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=task1,args=(qmdlvl,qmdlch,qtme,"#perplex: 100 early exag: 1 timing:$_plex100_exag1.csv"), name='t1')                          
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=task2,args=(qmdlvl,qmdlch,qtme,"#perplex: 100 early exag: 10 timing:$_plex100_exag10.cv"), name='t2')   

    # starting threads    
    t1.start() 
    t2.start() 

    while True:
        if qmdlvl.empty():
            print("Queue closed. Exiting thread.")   
            break
        try:
            item = qmdlvl.get(timeout=.5)

        except:
            continue
            print("Got item:", item)

    # wait until all threads finish 
    t1.join() 
    t2.join()
```

Below is the actual output I am getting  from the code in the main

```
    while True:
        if qmdlvl.empty():
            print("Queue closed. Exiting thread.")   
            break
        try:
            item = qmdlvl.get(timeout=.5)

        except:
            continue
            print("Got item:", item)
```

ID of process running main program: 6456
Main thread name: MainThread
Queue closed. Exiting thread.

I want to able to put the data frame into a queue inside the worker thread and access the same data frame in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

There are parameter mis-matches in my earlier code those have been corrected an a full working code presented below.

I stored the output of t-SNE directly into the queue and retrieved the same in the main thread. The next progression would be convert this to thread pool and sub-classing.

```
import threading
import queue
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import os
import time

def write_tsne_op(opdata,fname,header):

    with open(fname, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(header)
        for data_slice in opdata:
            np.savetxt(outfile, data_slice,delimiter=",")

def task1(ip_matrix,qmdlvalues,qmdlparam,plex,exag,qmdltime,qmdlhrfn,hderfname):
    string=""
    start=0
    end=0
    mdltiming=0
    start = time.time()
    tmpmdl1 = TSNE(perplexity=plex,early_exaggeration=exag, n_components=2,random_state=0,verbose=1)
    qmdlvalues.put(tmpmdl1.fit_transform(ip_matrix))    
    string = str(plex)+ "$" + str(exag)
    qmdlparam.put(string)
    qmdlhrfn.put(hderfname)
    end = time.time()
    mdltimig = end - start
    print(str(mdltiming)+"time")
    qmdltime.put(mdltiming)

def task2(ip_matrix,qmdlvalues,qmdlparam,plex,exag,qmdltime,qmdlhrfn,hderfname):
    string=""
    start=0
    end=0
    mdltiming=0
    start = time.time()    
    tmpmdl2 = TSNE(perplexity=plex,early_exaggeration=exag, n_components=2,random_state=0,verbose=1)    
    qmdlvalues.put(tmpmdl2.fit_transform(ip_matrix))
    string = str(plex)+ "$" + str(exag)
    qmdlparam.put(string)
    qmdlhrfn.put(hderfname)
    end = time.time()
    mdltimig = end - start
    qmdltime.put(mdltiming)

def task3(ip_matrix,qmdlvalues,qmdlparam,plex,exag,qmdltime,qmdlhrfn,hderfname):
    string=""
    start=0
    end=0
    mdltiming=0
    start = time.time()    
    tmpmdl3 = TSNE(perplexity=plex,early_exaggeration=exag, n_components=2,random_state=0,verbose=1)    
    qmdlvalues.put(tmpmdl3.fit_transform(ip_matrix))
    string = str(plex)+ "$" + str(exag)
    qmdlparam.put(string)
    qmdlhrfn.put(hderfname)
    end = time.time()
    mdltimig = end - start
    qmdltime.put(mdltiming)

def task4(ip_matrix,qmdlvalues,qmdlparam,plex,exag,qmdltime,qmdlhrfn,hderfname):
    string=""
    start=0
    end=0
    mdltiming=0
    start = time.time()    
    tmpmdl4 = TSNE(perplexity=plex,early_exaggeration=exag, n_components=2,random_state=0,verbose=1)    
    qmdlvalues.put(tmpmdl4.fit_transform(ip_matrix))
    string = str(plex)+ "$" + str(exag)
    qmdlparam.put(string)
    qmdlhrfn.put(hderfname)
    end = time.time()
    mdltimig = end - start
    qmdltime.put(mdltiming)

if __name__ == "__main__": 

    # print ID of current process 
    print("ID of process running main program: {}".format(os.getpid())) 

    # print name of main thread 
    print("Main thread name: {}".format(threading.main_thread().name)) 

    dense_mx2 = dense_mx
    dense_mx3 = dense_mx
    dense_mx4 = dense_mx

    qmdlvl = queue.Queue()
    qmdlch = queue.Queue()
    qmdltme = queue.Queue()
    qmdlhdrfname = queue.Queue()

    perplex = 200

    # creating threads 
    exag=10
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=task1,args=(dense_mx,qmdlvl,qmdlch,perplex,exag,qmdltme,qmdlhdrfname,"#perplex: 200 early exag: 10 timing:$_plex200_exag10.csv"), name='t1')                          

    exag=30
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=task2,args=(dense_mx2,qmdlvl,qmdlch,perplex,exag,qmdltme,qmdlhdrfname,"#perplex: 200 early exag: 30 timing:$_plex200_exag30.cv"), name='t2')   

    exag=50
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=task3,args=(dense_mx3,qmdlvl,qmdlch,perplex,exag,qmdltme,qmdlhdrfname,"#perplex: 200 early exag: 50 timing:$_plex200_exag50.csv"), name='t3')                          

    exag=100
    t4 = threading.Thread(target=task4,args=(dense_mx4,qmdlvl,qmdlch,perplex,exag,qmdltme,qmdlhdrfname,"#perplex: 200 early exag: 100 timing:$_plex200_exag100.cv"), name='t4')   

    # starting threads 
    t1.start() 
    t2.start() 
    t3.start() 
    t4.start() 



    # wait until all threads finish 
    t1.join() 
    t2.join() 
    t3.join() 
    t4.join() 

    while True:
        if qmdlvl.empty():
            print("Queue closed. Exiting thread.")   
            break
        try:
            item1 = qmdlvl.get(timeout=.5)
            item2 = qmdlch.get(timeout=.5)
            item3 = qmdltme.get(timeout=.5)
            header,fname = qmdlhdrfname.get(timeout=.5).split('$')
        except:
            continue        
        write_tsne_op(item1,fname,header)
```